# Gradle not downloading the complete dependencies in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying downloading dependencies in Android Studio. But when the download is complete and is time for the building process, errors come out in values folders mostly e.g attr not found and so many, I have tried uninstalling the idea and reinstall it again. And also to download one dependency one by one but still the same thing. Please help me. Thanks for the time you will be using in order to help me.
Here are the errors I'm getting

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar]
C:\Users\utr\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-1.0.0.aar\b3b942d506166776b316120faeb705cb\res\values-v28\values-v28.xml
Error:(9, 5) error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.
C:\Users\utr\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-1.0.0.aar\b3b942d506166776b316120faeb705cb\res\values\values.xml
Error:(1304, 5) error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.
Error:(1304, 5) error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.
C:\Users\utr\ApkProjects\BiBlog\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values-v28\values-v28.xml
Error:(11) error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.
Error:(7) resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.
Error:(11) resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.
C:\Users\utr\ApkProjects\BiBlog\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml
Error:(400) resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.
Error:(400) resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.
```

I have got these errors after adding

```
 implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
```

Comment: I would update your question with the error(s) that you are seeing.

Comment: Yes, of course go ahead

Comment: No, I am saying you need to edit your post with the errors that you see within Android Studio. Otherwise we will just be guessing about the issue(s).